# Remocon Hydro Android app/Turtlebot Pairing error

Tags: turtlebot, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all.

I''m encountering a problem now when pairing my android device with the turtlebot. Using the Robot Remocon App (hydro), i managed to detect the turtlebot under "Scan the local network". After loading,  it instantly display this error:

> org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException:
> timed out waiting for a gateway_info
> publication

<--screenshot image here--> = http: //tinypic.com/view.php?pic=5wuv7&s=8

However, i did set my ROS_IP/ROS_HOSTNAME/ROS_MASTER_URI on the turtlebot for multi-device-pc communication as the ros wiki tutorial states = (http: //wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/Network%20Configuration).

any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance guys.

tried following the answer to a similar question "here" =

http: //answers.ros.org/question/110196/android-rocon_app_manager-pairing-error/

but to no avail. (so i decided to bring this up again)

insufficient karma to post links. sigh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175178/remocon-hydro-android-app/turtlebot-pairing-error/) by [syaz nyp fyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/18948/syaz-nyp-fyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2014-06-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-06-30**:
I asked a similar question there...are you by chance using an android that exposes two network interfaces?

**Comment by [syaz nyp fyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/18948/syaz-nyp-fyp/) on 2014-07-01**:
ive checked and i doubt it's exposing to 2 network interfaces.

Either ROS_IP or ROS_HOSTNAME needs to be set in bashrc right? just one will do? and it's supposed to be ROS_HOSTNAME=IP_OF_TURTLEBOT? am i right? I've done it. I'm really confused on what seems to be the problem now. thks a lot daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally got it working. Thanks to everyone.
For the machine that is running roscore, you need not need to worry about ROS_MASTER_URI or ROS_HOSTNAME but you need to select the IP of your machine on the internal network. Exporting ROS_IP in ~/.bashrc

> export ROS_IP=172.20.10.8

Need to make sure that ROS_IP is also set in the etc/hosts file by adding:

> 172.20.10.8      ROS_IP

---

Originally posted by [syaz nyp fyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/18948/syaz-nyp-fyp/) with karma: 167 on 2014-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jie Sky](https://answers.ros.org/users/20509/jie-sky/) on 2014-10-19**:
I really have set the ROS_IP like above,but I failed.Can you tell me how to set it